# Cannot read property 'messageHandlers' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I want to pass JavaScript variable to Swift.
I get an error in JavaScript & search for that but I didn't get any result.
The error is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'messageHandlers' of undefined

Any one can help?

My code in Xcode:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,WKScriptMessageHandler,WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView = WKWebView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 

        webView.frame = view.bounds
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        let url = URL(string: "MyUrl")!
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(urlRequest)
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(webView)
        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        userContentController.add(self, name: "test")
    }

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print("Name: \(message.name)")
        print("Body: \(message.body as! String)")
   }
}
```

And in JavaScript:

```
click: event => {
window.webkit.messageHandlers.test.postMessage("hi");
}
```

Comment: have you tried window.postMessage("hi"); ?

Comment: @dhruvsoni yes but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the "test" message handler, you need to add it to your `webView`'s configuration, but you are not doing so.

By including this message handler into your `WKUserContentController` object, your webView will define a new function `window.webkit.messageHandlers.name.postMessage(messageBody)` that can be called in all frames.

Try changing your `viewDidLoad()` to the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()

    let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
    userContentController.add(self, name: "test")

    config.userContentController = userContentController

    webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: config) // Create webView with the configuration

    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    let url = URL(string: "MyUrl")!
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(urlRequest)
    webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
    view.addSubview(webView)
}
```

Comment: I'm still have webkit undefined. The only difference from my code and yours is that I'm using SwiftUI.

```
func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration();
        let controller = WKUserContentController();
        controller.add(self, name: "ipcEvent");
        webViewConfiguration.userContentController = controller;
        
        self.browser = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webViewConfiguration);
        return self.browser;
    }
```

In my case, window.webkit is undefined so all the rest fail...