# How to use 'window.webkit.messageHandlers' in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use `window.webkit.messageHandlers.xxx` ,call the `xxx` iOS method .
like this in React:

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';

   .....

 componentDidMount() {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.test.postMessage("Did finish loading");
    }
```

but compile error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'messageHandlers' of undefined
```

what should I import ?

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771215/wkwebkit-javascript-on-loaded-page-finds-window-webkit-is-undefined

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745833/cannot-read-property-messagehandlers-of-undefined